# Continuous Deployment on azure VM

Tags: .net, azure, bitbucket, devops, autodeploy

I am using bitbucket as repo and I want to create an autodeploy with azure.

We are not using azure web apps , Its azure VM hosting IIS and application.
There are multiple applications on one VM.

How I can enable autodeployment in this scenario any help or tool suggestions are welcom.

Comment: It is same with your local. What do you use local?

Comment: we are currently publishing to a folder and copying to VM by using RDP, a complete manual process.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Bitbucket, I assumed that you could leverage [Bitbucket Pipelines](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bitbucket-pipelines-792496469.html) for Continuous Delivery your Bitbucket Cloud repository to Azure VM. Here is a tutorial about [Continuous integration and delivery of web apps from Atlassian Bitbucket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/continuous-integration-delivery-of-web-apps-from-atlassian-bitbucket/), I assume that you could use the `deploy-to-azure.bash` script that use the FTP service from your VM to deploy your repository to the web application hosted on your Azure VM. You could follow this [tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/get-started-with-bitbucket-pipelines-792298921.html) for getting started with Bitbucket Pipelines and refer to this [Pipelines-to-Azure Sample](https://bitbucket.org/mojall/pipeline2azure/src/4bf47049e4d1?at=master) for setting up FTP deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an external tool to perform the deployment. And possibly you might have to write some scripts to automate the steps that needs to be executed.

There are many tools commercial or open source available that can perform this task. Among many, the popular ones are: Puppet, Chef, Powershell DSC, Octopus Deploy, etc.